# error TS6231: Could not resolve the path '' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, function

I'm working on **firebase functions** with **typescript** and this error appears in the console while running `tsc . -watch`:

```
[12:19:41 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

error TS6231: Could not resolve the path '' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation

[12:19:45 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

I have no idea where this might be arising from. I haven't changed anything since the last time this was working.

Any solutions?

Comment: Which version of node you are using? 14 of 16?

Answer (score 41):

I got this error when I used `tsc init`  instead of  `tsc --init`

Comment: the --init flag worked for me to 

Answer (score 15):

Try to **compile the project indicating the path of tsconfig.json** (configuration file) or the directory where it is. Using --project.

```
tsc --project tsconfig.json
```

or

```
tsc --project ./
```

Here in this link [tsc CLI Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) you can find more options to compile your project.

Comment: For some reason it solved my problem, even though I have the same error but without using `-watch`. My  config file is named `tsconfig.json` so unclear why `tsc` would not be able to find it

Comment: Yes, tsc finds tsconfig.json by default. But for me tsc stopped finding the configuration file (tsconfig.json) after adding eslint and webpack. So when I wanted to compile just the typescript I had to use "--project".

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
tsc
```

And not:

```
tsc . // remove the dot
```

So update package.json to:

```
"script: {
   "build": "rm -rf build && tsc", // delete build folder then complile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `tsc -watch`, it fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing this same error and it was obfuscating the real error under the covers.

Try compiling your typescript in one step, and then running the entry file as the second step. So essentially, *not* in watch mode.

---

FWIW, the error that was actually occurring for me was a failure of the code to read my environment variables. I traced it to an update from `dotenv` that [broke the ability](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/367) for `NODE_ENV` to be properly set (on a Windows machine) in my startup script.

Comment: Thank you! When I run my `dev:watch` command, which basically runs our `build` command with nodemon watch, I see this error, but when I run `build` directly, I see a different error that seems to preclude the error in this SO question.

Answer (score 1):

from my experience, when you create a new tsconfig.json, there is like

```
,
  "files": [
    "\\",
    "\\"
  ]
```

in the bottom.
so I just removed it, and that's solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link, it worked for me: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-could-not-resolve-path-with-extensions-ts-tsx

**This block to be specific:
For example, if you issue a command tsc init, the TypeScript compiler thinks that you want to emit JS for a file called init. Instead, you should use the init flag, tsc --init.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "files" in the bottom of the archive. It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

remove `"files": [""]` use `"rootDir": "./src", "outDir": "./output"` keepall .ts files inside 'src' folder

Answer (score 0):

In package.json for Windows

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf dist && tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm run watch\"",
    "watch": "nodemon \"src/app.ts\" --watch \"./src\""}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.

**First.** By invoking tsc with no input files, in which case the compiler searches for the tsconfig.json file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.

```
$ npx tsc
```

* Caution: Do not use dot in the first example

**Second.** By invoking tsc with no input files and a --project (or just -p) command line option that specifies the path of a directory containing a tsconfig.json file, or a path to a valid .json file containing the configurations.

```
$ npx tsc --project tsconfig.json
```

or

```
$ npx tsc --project .
```

Answer (score -1):

change the name of your file from .tsc to .ts
and it will work :)

Comment: That's not anywhere in the question though? Are you trying to say that it's due to a faulty extension name? Please [edit] and explain.